# Passing $_POST/$_GET as a parameter to function

Tags: php

I came across an interesting piece of PHP code which has me a bit stumped as to *why* the author has chosen to do this.

```
function do_something($db, $post_vars){
    foreach($post_vars as $key => $value{
        $vars[$key] = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $value);
    }
    return $vars;
}

$db = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 
do_something($db, $_POST);
```

It got me thinking about why someone would want to pass $_POST as a variable and just not access it directly inside the function? The only benefit I could think of (and this was a bit of a long shot) was if we were to append other information to $_POST before calling the function (such as):

```
function do_something($db, $post_vars){
    foreach($post_vars as $key => $value{
        $vars[$key] = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $value);
    }
    return $vars;
}

$db = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 

foreach($_POST as $post_key => $post_value){
    $post[$post_key] = $post_value;
}

$post['my_custom_var'] = "a";

do_something($db, $post);
```

There is, however, no evidence of this practise anywhere in the code. Just calls to `do_something()` with `$_POST` being passed as an arugment.

My question then is, is there any benefit in doing it like this that I've missed or did the author simply not understand that $_POST is a global variable?

**A complete long shot:** Is there perhaps even any well intended "later additions" they could make to this (such as my example) that would *almost* justify this practise or is this just a case of misunderstanding. Or perhaps is there a security implication that could justify the practise?

Comment: It's rather pointless, trying to do a somewhat better job of what php's old dead/gone/not-missed `magic_quotes` was doing - assuming that EVERYTHING that EVER gets posted to php will only ever get used in an sql query context.

Comment: I think this work makes this function more general, and more usable for future uses.

Comment: Maybe the developer was trying to externalize the dependency so the function could be unit-tested?  With this particular function that doesn't seem necessary, but for actual business logic it would make sense.

Comment: Yeah, seems as if they've picked a standard and applied it to everything, at the expense of extra key strokes.

Comment: The primordial mistake in that code was picking `mysqli` over `PDO` in the first place. You wouldn't need this *workaround* when using prepared statements - which happens to be only tolerable with PDO.

Comment: @ScottMcGready: When someone really likes their hammer, everything looks like a nail.

Comment: @David exactly my thought. I just wanted to give him the benefit of the doubt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMHO it's a practice of abstraction, and there are benefits:

1. Generality: by receiving `$_POST` as a parameter, the function becomes less tightly coupled to `$_POST`. The function may serve more scenarios & possibly be more reusable.
2. Inversion of control: because the function's dependency(`$_POST`) is injected from outside, you have more control over the function. It is a bit unlikely but let's suppose your form has been updated and now you need to submit via GET method. Without modifying the function's body, passing in `$_GET` on the caller's side, is enough to reflect the change.
3. Test fixture isolation: To mock FORM inputs to test a certain code path in the function, it is better access global states (such as `$_POST`) in an abstracted way, so that the test itself does not bring side effects to other part of the system.

Comment: 1 seems understandable. 2 is very unlikely but still a good idea. 3 seems like the most likely candidate here.

Comment: Marked this as the answer since it provided a few options as to what the original author had intended.

Answer (score 2):

In general, there is a very good reason to pass `$_POST` or `$_GET` or whatever array you want as argument instead of accessing it through the auto-global variables. It's called ["dependency injection"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and it's a key feature for testable code.

Another reason to not use auto-globals (or global variables, in general) is the readability of the code.

Compare:

```
function do_something($db, array $post_vars) {
    // many lines of code here, you don't want to read them
}

do_something($db, $_POST);
```

with

```
function do_something_else($db) {
    // many lines of code here that use $_POST, you don't want to read them either
}

do_something_else($db);
```

In the first case its clear that function `do_something()` operates over the values of `$_POST` (or `$_GET` or whatever other array full of data you pass it as argument). You don't have to read the function's code to know that; all the relevant information is displayed in the function header and in the example usage.

In the second case, the behaviour of function `do_something_else()` depends on the content of `$_POST` but one cannot know this without looking at its code.

---

Back to the code you posted, it doesn't look like it was written having testability in mind.

Take a look only at:

```
foreach($_POST as $post_key => $post_value){
    $post[$post_key] = $post_value;
}
```

It basically does `$post = $_POST` in more words.

Comment: I see where you're coming from but there's a huge docblock at the top of the function describing how it's doing x with $_POST vars... Guess I just inherited a mess!

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to sanitize the $_POST Superglobal before passing it as an argument of a function, then escape it inside the function that has your query logic.

Answer (score -2):

What he does is escaping every POST variable through [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/ro/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) function, which makes sure you avoid SQL Injection attacks.Then he returns the array (with escaped values) by calling : return $vars;

He might have used a function to do this because he intends to repeat the steps several times throughout the application and he might just call that function and passing the variables instead of writing the code over and over again.

MAKE SURE YOU ALWAYS ESCAPE USER INPUT BEFORE MAKING ANY DATABASE CALLS.

Comment: You've totally missed the point of the question. I wasn't asking for a clarification of what the code does... I already know that. I was asking why someone would choose to pass `$_POST` as an argument rather than accessing it directly in the function.

Comment: Because a function is a general group of code that can be used multiple times. He might want to use that function with other data as well ..for example $_GET arrays, custom arrays etc...But I presumed you have gone beyond the role of a function

Comment: I understand what a function is thanks, I was asking a specific question about that. The other answers have indicated why someone may pass `$_POST` or `$_GET` vars as arguments to a function, like you're alluding to in the middle of your comment. I'm confused though what you mean by "But I presumed you have gone beyond the role of a function"... what?